# how to remove function in url with .htaccess on codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

how to remove function controller in url with .htaccess.

example

```
www.domain.com/controller/function/variable
```

to

```
www.domain.com/controller/variable
```

i try write the .htaccess file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 

    RewriteRule ^index.php/catalog/([^./.]+)$ ./catalog/index/$1   
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

catalog is controller and index is function

but not works, it bring out the 404 page.

thanks.

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve, you can set the function as private.

Comment: It can also be done with `config/routes.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by [CodeIgniter Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

go to application/config/routes.php and write rout rules this way

```
$route['controller/(:any)'] = "controller/function/$1";
```

let your controller name `article` and function name `details` so you can write routing rules for this function following

```
$route['article/(:any)'] = "article/details/$1";
```

Hope it will help full for you.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using [Codeigniter routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

**config/routes.php**

```
$route['controller/(:any)'] = "controller/function/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use routing directly in your framework. You probably need read this article.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html